# two table view data management on iphone

Tags: iphone

i have **2 buttons A and B both display tableview** and data **initially same data** 
but then in **B there is a search button so when user serach tableViewB data changes** and then if i **press A
then i can see the data shown in B** **my earlier data A is override by B**
how to solve this issues   so that i can see my old data in A

i did
**1) 
different IB outlets name  of tableview
2) 
changed the Cell Identifier name**
 but no sucess kindly suggest

Table A code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView0 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //UITableView *tableView;
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cells";


    //self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,searchBar.bounds.size.height,320,480);






    cell= [tableView0 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil ) {


        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        //cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


#pragma mark BG image for tableView


}
```

Table B code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //UITableView *tableView;
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    //self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,searchBar.bounds.size.height,320,480);



    NSLog(@" what is the valuE%d",[appDelegate.books count]);


    cell= [tableview1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil ) {



        NSLog(@" table view cell value %d",[appDelegate.books count]);
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    //  cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally fixed the issue... concept is i was parsing same xml and was using same array thats why value was same , now i made 2 different xml parser and 2 different array holding data separately and its fixed

Thanks